# Is it possible to compile a Xamarin project as a library for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I need to create an API library for Android and iOS. I have experience working with Android projects, but zero experties in iOS. I was wondering if I could create a Project library in Xamarin that compiles as a JAR for Android and as an... I-don't-know-which-type for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't possible. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish there may be alternatives. If you are trying to make a library that can be used by others you could make it a Xamarin component - there is a component store you could put it on if you want it to be generally available, otherwise you can use any normal means of source or object distribution.

If you need to interact with a native app/library then you could make the C# code the "owner" of it and have it call into the native code. This works for both IOs and Android (and is used to work with e.g the play services from google).

Comment: Thanks, but I need the library to be available to native iOS and android projects. It is kinda of encapsulating a REST api client in the library, and give that library to other developers who can use the api.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is unfortunately not possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you need is a `Portable Class Library` also known as `PCL`. It allows you to create a project which can be referenced by all Xamarin supported platforms (such as iOs and Android). There are obviously limitations to the approach like not being able to reference platform specific libraries but in your case (of writing an API) it should suffice.
You can read more in [this link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I need the library to be available to native iOS and android projects. It is kinda of encapsulating a REST api client in the library, and give that library to other developers who can use the api.

Comment: Would work. You have a .Net REST component (which I use successfully) called RestSharp. You can wrap it and publish it to your developers as a customized API. Give it a go.

Comment: but the developers would have to use that .Net REST component with Xamarin? Because I do not have control over what they use, but I'm pretty sure that they work under Xcode (for iOS) and android SDK (or NDK).

Comment: I see what you mean now. What you make on Xamarin stays on Xamarin. I think what you're looking for isn't available.